# Three Digit Square w/ Numbers 1-9

Tags: square-numbers

Using a computer/program, can anyone figure out:

The square of 567 is 321,489.  These two numbers contain each of the digits from 1 to 9 exactly once between them.  What other three-digit number and its square have this property?

And also explain how?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that you can use a computer program. The easiest way to do this is using Python. First, create a function that [turns the number into a list of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270320/turn-a-single-number-into-single-digits-python), like so:

```
def digits(n):
    return [int(d) for d in str(n)]
```

Now, let's say our three-digit number is $a$. We can then combine the digits of $a$ with the digits of $a^2$ using list concatenation:

```
all_digits = digits(a)+digits(a**2)
```

Finally, we need to make sure `all_digits` contains all the digits from $1$ through $9$. The easiest way to do this is to sort them and to see if it is the array $1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 9$:

```
if sorted(all_digits) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]: print(a)
```

Finally, we need to loop $a$ from $100$ to $999$ to get through all the three-digit numbers. We can do this with a `for` loop, so the full program becomes:

```
def digits(n):
    return [int(d) for d in str(n)]

for a in range(100, 999+1):
    all_digits = digits(a)+digits(a**2)
    if sorted(all_digits) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]: print(a)
```

This prints out $567$ and $854$, so the final answer is $854$.